# Console output awaits coroutineScope {} body completion

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

there is an example:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
 
fun main() = runBlocking { // this: CoroutineScope
 
    launch {
        delay(200L)
        println("Task from runBlocking")
    }
 
    coroutineScope { // Creates a coroutine scope
        launch {
            delay(500L)
            println("Task from nested launch")
        }
 
        delay(100L)
        println("Task from coroutine scope") // This line will be printed before the nested launch
    }
 
    println("Coroutine scope is over") // This line is not printed until the nested launch completes
}
```

The result is this:

*Task from coroutine scope*

*Task from runBlocking*

*Task from nested launch*

*Coroutine scope is over*

Can you explain why the output on line 20 (**println("Coroutine scope is over")**) occurs at the very end, after the coroutineScope{} body completes?

I just thought, that line 20 was running on the **main thread**, and that **launch{}** and **coroutineScope{}**  created coroutines running in parallel. So I expected that

*Coroutine scope is over*

to be displayed at the very beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for the function `coroutineScope`, it says that it suspends and doesn't return until all its children coroutines are complete:

> This function returns as soon as the given block and all its children coroutines are completed.

If you create a child scope and call launch on it, the behavior will be like what you were expecting:

```
fun main() = runBlocking {

    launch {
        delay(200L)
        println("Task from runBlocking")
    }

    val scope = CoroutineScope(coroutineContext)
    scope.launch {
        launch {
            delay(500L)
            println("Task from nested launch")
        }

        delay(100L)
        println("Task from coroutine scope")
    }

    println("Coroutine scope is over")
}
```

outputs

```
Coroutine scope is over
Task from coroutine scope
Task from runBlocking
Task from nested launch
```

Comment: Why not write `launch { ... }` instead of `CoroutineScope(coroutineContext).launch { ... }`?

Comment: Just showing the difference between `CoroutineScope()` and `coroutineScope` since OP seems to be exploring how to create an independent CoroutineScope.